# Is it possible to convert types in SmartPy?

Tags: smartpy, types

For example, converting a TMutez into a TString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.

There are no built-in convertors in Michelson.

Some operations are doable nonetheless.
For example, the [string manipulations](https://smartpy.io/dev/index.html?template=stringManipulations.py) template demonstrates kind of extreme string manipulations in SmartPy.
For mutez, you could start to convert to int (by dividing by 1 mutez) and then use the same technics.